# Noetherian quotient module

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a left Noetherian $R$-module, and let $J$ be an ideal of $R$. Then why is $J^i M/J^{i+1}M$ a Noetherian module? I can't seem to figure this out.

edit: I do not require $R$ to be a commutative ring. It is an arbitrary ring.

Comment: $J^iM$ is a submodule of $M$ and your quotient is a quotient of that...

Comment: Indeed, my question was silly. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

$J^iM$ is a submodule of $M$ and your quotient is a quotient of that.

Since noetherianity is inherited by submodules and quotients, your result follows at once.

Comment: "Noetherianity"! Something about that amuses me.